# Which Visual Studio project type does PhoneJS use?

Tags: visual-studio, nuget, phonejs

I am looking at phoneJs and they talk about using nuget. However they don't say what their solution is. It looks like it is a javascript solution project but I don't see that in VS2012.

[PhoneJs](http://phonejs.devexpress.com/Documentation/Tutorial/Getting_Started/Set_Up_Your_Environment#Getting_Started_Set_Up_Your_Environment_Add_Libraries_Use_a_NuGet_Package)

Answer (score 0):

It can be ASP.NET project (WebForms, MVC) or Window Store Javascript application.

Screenshots at the page you refer most probably display Windows Store project. This kind of project is only available in Windows 8.

P.S. Additional project templates with PhoneJS are included in [DevExtreme](http://www.devexpress.com/Products/HTML-JS/): [documentation](http://help.devexpress.com/DevExtreme/Documentation/Howto/Project_Templates).